# ParquetWriter getting Cannot run program "chmod"

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, parquet, hadoop2

Hi I'm using mac with current java version 17.0.1-tem
I'm Trying to create local parquet file using ParquetWriter :
Using this code :

```
AvroParquetWriter.builder[GenericRecord](path)
      .withSchema(avroSchema)
      .withCompressionCodec(COMPRESSION_CODE)
      .withPageSize(PAGE_SIZE)
      .withRowGroupSize(BLOCK_SIZE)
      .withDictionaryEncoding(ENABLE_DICT)
      .withWriteMode("overwrite")
      .withValidation(true)
      .build()
```

This cause the following exception

```
Cannot run program "chmod": error=17, File exists
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chmod": error=17, File exists
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:938)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:1307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:1289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:978)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.createOrOverwrite(HadoopOutputFile.java:81)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:246)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.<init>(ParquetWriter.java:280)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter$Builder.build(ParquetWriter.java:535)
```

Comment: Can you show a little more of the code.  It's clear from the error the file already exists.  Can you creating this in a 'clean' folder and see if the issue persists?

Comment: It looks like you don't have permission to write in `path` (or to create that directory)